# Structure for a view with an optional secondary model in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model, viewmodel

I have an MVC3 project I'm working on that has a View with an associated strongly typed view model. I've been tasked with adding an optional section to this view that would contain the data for a second model, about half of which is shared with the first model.

My question is, what is the best way to implement this? Should I just add the object that the optional model represents to the view model and try to map values from there?

If I do it this way, how can I associate the editors with both models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the optional model to the view model is the best choice, because, unlike ViewBag, it's type safe and you can still leverage the html helpers. Just remember to check the second model for null reference before you render it (since it's optional).
For sharing properties, your view model can have special getters/setters that would mantain both models synchronized internally.

Comment: So if I were to use the member properties on the viewModel I would have to manually assign the values to them? Or would the MVC binder do that for me somehow?


The other question I have is how would this be done with the database. As of right now I've added a property on the nested model in the database that stores the ID of the primary model so that I can tell if one has already been added, rather than making a new entry every time. Is that a decent way to set it up or is there a better way I should be doing this?

Comment: The MVC binder would only go as far as invoking the setter of the property you're using. Inside this setter, you can place your code for updating the values of the nested models; something like `string Name { set { this.firstModel.Name = value; this.secondModel.Name = value; }`. Though this is possible, it might not be the best design, so about your second question, I can't say if that's a decent way of setting it up without having more information about this particular use case. Perhaps you can provide more information about why you need shared properties in the first place.

Comment: Sure, essentially I'm writing a data entry application that takes in information for mechanical issues with vehicles. The problem is that if a vehicle misses a run because of a mechanical issue I need to automatically enter a missed run instance, which shares about half of its fields with the mechanical issue entry form. So rather than having them enter half of the information a second time, I would like to be able to use the existing information.

Comment: In this case, in my opinion I think it would be a better design if you extract those properties common to both objects, and turn them into a third object (like 'VehicleOccurrence' or something like that). Then, you could make both objects,'missed run' and 'mechanical issue', have a reference to this 'occurrence'. Using inheritance instead of reference would also be an option, better than duplicate these properties IMO.

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand what your asking and this is how I have accomplished it in the past.

Add the optional model as a parameter in the view model and then create a partial view that is typed to that optional model.   If the criteria is met that allows that partial view to display then you pass the viewmodel.optionalmodel to that partial view.

You just have to be a bit careful about the overlap of parameters causing any headaches (as in null references)